# NSHTMLTextDocumentType downloads images synchronously

Tags: html, ios, image, nsstring, nsattributedstring

I am trying to display HTML text in a `UITextView` with this `NSAttributedString`:

`[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]} documentAttributes:nil error:nil]`

The HTML Text I am trying to display has images in it. The problem is, that this method is downloading these synchronously. I would like to handle image download and display myself. Is there any way I can tell the system not to download these images, but to assign a placeholder when I execute this?

Comment: I worked around this and even though it is not loading images anymore, it turns out `NSHTMLTextDocumentType` is always slow and locks your UI for a long time, as it is not backgroundable. Thanks Apple.

Answer (score -1):

You can create the attributed string synchronously and show a HUD while the processing is happening. Just create a custom delegate that will inform your class when the creation is complete.

Comment: Waiting several seconds before something, that could absolutely happen immediately, results in senselessly bad user experience.

Comment: I agree that it'd be best if Apple's NSHTMLTextDocumentType worked faster and did not lock the UI.  Since it's not backgroundable as you mentioned in your answer, how are you making this happen immediately?

Comment: Using a custom HTML Processor. Started out using https://github.com/dbowen/NSAttributedString-DDHTML/ and made my own custom one in swift which I may open source once it's complete.

Comment: Ahh very cool.  However, initial poster asked how to assign a placeholder image, and I believe my response would allow that behavior.  Without bringing in a 3rd party library, the delegation method may be the easiest option.  I'd also argue that looking a placeholder image (perhaps animated) would not result in a senselessly bad experience, especially if the initial poster wants to show a placeholder image.  Even though you have offered a reasonable and well-informed comment/answer, I don't think your down vote is appropriate.

Comment: As the initial poster, I asked for a way to make this faster (giving the example of assigning placeholder images inside the text, but still being able to look at the text immediately). As this is not possible, in any way, with Apple's API, your answer does go against my intention of removing the lag.

Comment: You had asked to assign a placeholder while the images download synchronously instead of asking how to speed up the process.  That is what the answer above provides a solution for.  Please consider asking questions more explicitly so you can get the answers for your actual issues.